# Add custom app to the favorite applications tab

Tags: 22.04, dock, favorites

I need to add a custom app to the favorites tab on the dock. I have tried this solution:

https://averagelinuxuser.com/ubuntu_custom_launcher_dock/

This works up until the point where I need to make the file executable, at which point when I enter the command it appears to have worked until I check if the app is now in the Applications menu, which it is not. The tutorial was made for version 20 so I believe it does not work on version 22.04.

Is it still possible to add custom apps to the favorites?

Comment: Yes it is possible to add custom apps to the favorites, but they first need to  be picked up by the Application menu. That only will happen if the launcher is in a correct location and has valid content. Do not use `/usr/share/applications/`, a directory managed by the APT system. Instead use `/usr/local/share/applications/`

Answer (score 0):

After create a `yourapp.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/`

make the file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/yourapp.desktop
```

now search by the app name in activities, if you found it right click on it and choose add to favorites.

Comment: There is no need to make the file executable.